# ArgumentException with Export-SPWeb Lists

Tags: list, backup, splistitem, export

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Export-SPWeb "http://win-oql2facn6h8/" -itemurl "List
s/Disney" -path "c:\Backups\disney.cmp"
Export-SPWeb : <nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
At line:1 char:13
+ Export-SPWeb <<<<  "http://win-oql2facn6h8/" -itemurl "Lists/Disney" -path "c
:\Backups\disney.cmp"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletExportWeb:
   SPCmdletExportWeb) [Export-SPWeb], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletExportWe
   b
```

Above was the error message. I can access the list at http://win-oql2facn6h8/Lists/Disney/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EList&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence

I suspect that there could be typos in my cmdlet that leaded to this error, but I've been unable to locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just forgot a slash here: -itemurl "/Lists/Disney"

Answer (score 2):

This works fine with Powershell!

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://win-oql2facn6h8/ -ItemURL /Lists/Disney -Path c:\Backups\disney.cmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the full URL in your -ItemURL parameter

```
Export-SPWeb "http://win-oql2facn6h8/" -itemurl "http://win-oql2facn6h8/Lists/Disney" -path "c:\Backups\disney.cmp"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gave me the same error :(